# How to stop a flume agent gracefully

Tags: hdfs, flume

Many websites suggest using kill -9 when stopping a flume agent.

However, when I stop the agent with kill -9, the HDFS sink files left open forever(as *.tmp).

## How can I stop a flume agent gracefully so that, the agent close all the writing files on the HDFS before it stops.

```
#Name the components on this agent
agent.sources = r1
agent.sinks = k1
agent.channels = c1

#Configure the Kafka Source
agent.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
agent.sources.r1.batchSize = 1000
agent.sources.r1.batchDurationMillis = 3000
agent.sources.r1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = <server1>:6667,<server2>:6667
agent.sources.r1.kafka.topics = 1-agent1-thread
agent.sources.r1.kafka.consumer.group.id = flume_agent_thread

#Describe the sink
agent.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /user/flume/kafka-data/1-agent1-thread/%y%m%d/%H
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = 1-agent1-thread

#Describing sink with the problem of Encoding
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

#Describing sink with the problem of many hdfs files
### Roll a file after certain amount of events occurs  ###
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.batchSize = 100
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.idleTimeout = 300
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.closeTries = 0
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.retryInterval = 200

#Use a channel which buffers events in memory
agent.channels.c1.type = memory
agent.channels.c1.capacity = 10000
agent.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 1000

#Bind the source and sink to the channel
agent.sources.r1.channels = c1
agent.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `kill -TERM` which is the standard way to kill all Hadoop-related services.

Flume will have a `SIGTERM` handler ([See Application.java](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=blob;f=flume-ng-node/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/node/Application.java;h=406bb7de61d95895671dc283644d036882afa07d;hb=trunk#l366)) which should clean up all open files.

```
ShutdownHook() -> stop() -> stopAllComponents()
```

`kill -9` should only be used if you've tried `kill -TERM` and the flume agent is still hung.

Comment: Thanks, using only kill command makes flume agent to close all the tmp files!!